# How can I find the bootloader IP address of a router?

Tags: networking, router, bootloader, flashing

I'm trying to flash a router I have access to with OpenWrt, the router is not flashing with the OpenWrt bin file through it's webui.

So I have to flash it with the TFTP method, for this I have to create a TFTP server on a PC and set the PC's IP address to bootloader's IP address so that the router will get OpenWrt bin file and flash.

But I don't know the router's bootloader IP address, I know the normal IP address of the router. Is there a way to find the bootloader IP address of the router?

Comment: depends on the make/model/version of the router - which you haven't specified - the information you seek, however, would most likely be available in the hardware page for your router on openwrt's website - for mainstream supported devices, their documentation is usually the place to go for how-to install openwrt

Comment: @Bravo I thought about mentioning the router's model number but I thought it might be flagged for advertising it. In case you want to know the router is TP-Link C58HP. The information provided on the OpenWrt's website for this router or any router for that matter is neither specific nor detailed. It doesn't say to which IP I should configure the PC, should I run TFTP server or client, how to initiate the router's TFTP transfer.